# Multiple installations of Java on the same machine

Tags: java, jenkins

I need to have 2 version of Java on the same Docker image:

- Java 7 for the developers
- Java 8 for running a Jenkins-slave

Because we're running quiet old software, the solution was:

```
RUN echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jdk && \
    update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java && \
    apt-get clean
```

I tried to remove the update-alternatives and simply change the Jenkins $PATH-environment on the Jenkins slave to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/utilities/bin/
```

Unfortunately this would still keep Java 7 as the default Java.

An alternative would be to make Java 8 the default using update-alternatives and change the version of Java to use by the Maven build in the Jenkins pipeline.

1. What is the best way to be able to use both versions of Java?
2. What should be my default version?
3. How do I configure the other (Maven build or Jenkins slave) to use the other (non-default) version of Java?

Comment: **Nobody** can tell you what the *correct* default for *your* setup is. Because it is your setup, your requirements. My two cents: Java8. You dont ask how to use Java 7, you only ask yourself how you get completely rid of it.

Comment: Question 1 is a bit of a misnomer, you don't "run" Java. You run Java applications and you run them through a specific Java runtime. You can easily install multiple runtimes on the same machine without conflict, the only thing that you need to figure out is what the proper way is to make a tool use a specific runtime if the default isn't the one. That differs per tool. For Jenkins, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/858902) seems to hold a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) for this. 
SDKMAN! is a tool for managing parallel versions of multiple Software Development Kits on most Unix based systems